# Unity3d - How to apply transparency in a video sourced from a URL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I do have a project that streams a video from a URL. That video has a transparent background. Every time the video plays, the background color is set to pink.

I've tried only when using a video clip and the video is already on the project. I could set its decoder into VP8 in order to enable its Alpha channel.

Comment: How do you stream and display it? (I suspect a `VideoPlayer` component?)

Comment: I use a VideoPlayer Component on its URL field. but the video has a pink background on it.

Comment: Do you know the original video's file format and encoding etc?